# ¿Como hacer zoom a un JPanel y a sus componentes?

Tags: java

Estoy creando un editor de etiquetas en java y quiero lograr hacer que el usuario pueda hacer zoom al área de trabajo (`JPanel`) ademas de también cambien de tamaño los componentes que estén dentro.

Aqui mi codigo:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) PPanel1.getGraphics();
int w = PPanel1.getWidth();
int h = PPanel1.getHeight();

double scale = 1.25;

g2.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
g2.scale(scale, scale);
g2.translate(-w / 2, -h / 2);

PPanel1.paintComponents(g2);

PPanel1.updateUI();

PPanel1.setSize(PPanel1.getWidth() * 1.25, PPanel1.getHeight() * 1.25);
            CZoom.setSelectedIndex(cambiarPosicion);

d = new Dimension(PPanel1.getWidth(), PPanel1.getHeight());
PPanel1.setSize(d);
```

Hace zoom a los componentes si no cambio el tamaño del panel, pero cuando cambio de tamaño, no hace zoom a los componentes.

Comment: ¿Podrías pegar un poco más de código de la aplicación? Es para hacer pruebas. Una opción podría ser modificar la propiedad setResizable, poniéndola a false, de tal manera que no se pueda modificar el tamaño del Panel.

Comment: Bueno es que en si es todo lo que tengo para hacer zoom, nada mas tengo un panel que es `ppanel` y nada mas quiero que se haga zoom tanto el panel como las labels que contenga.

Comment: ¿Te sirvió la solución?

Comment: Giovani mira a ver si la respuesta de @alopezf1987 es valida y si lo es, considera marcarla como aceptada. Si no fuera valida, comentale bajo su publicacion por que no lo es para que pueda arreglarla.. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Varias cosas:

```
PPanel1.setSize(PPanel1.getWidth() * 1.25, PPanel1.getHeight() * 1.25);
CZoom.setSelectedIndex(cambiarPosicion);
```

- La primera instrucción no debería funcionar, ya que la anchura y la
  altura que reciben el método **setSize** son enteros (y ahí estás haciendo conversión a double de forma implícita al multiplicar por 1,25).
- **CZoom** y **cambiarPosicion** son dos variables cuyo origen desconozco.

Dicho esto, no especificas en qué clase de evento quieres que se produzca el cambio de tamaño, así que te lo he resuelto con **MouseEntered** y **MouseExited** (más información [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html)):

```
private void etiqueta1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    etiqueta1.setFont(new Font(
            etiqueta1.getFont().getName(),
            etiqueta1.getFont().getStyle(),
            etiqueta1.getFont().getSize() * 2));

    panel1.setSize(panel1.getSize().width + 100, panel1.getSize().height + 100);
    this.setSize(this.getSize().width + 100, this.getSize().height + 100);
}                                      

private void etiqueta1MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    etiqueta1.setFont(new Font(
            etiqueta1.getFont().getName(),
            etiqueta1.getFont().getStyle(),
            etiqueta1.getFont().getSize() / 2));

    panel1.setSize(panel1.getSize().width - 100, panel1.getSize().height - 100);
    this.setSize(this.getSize().width - 100, this.getSize().height - 100);
}
```

**Estado Inicial**

[image: Estado Inicial]

Cuando desplazo el ratón sobre la etiqueta, lo que hago es modificar el tamaño de la fuente al doble de la actual, e incremento el tamaño del objeto de la clase [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) y del propio [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) en 100 pixeles.

[image: Estado Cambiado]

Cuando me salgo de la etiqueta invierto el proceso, dejándolo todo como estaba.

[image: Estado Inicial]

Comment: No es exactamente lo que estaba buscando, pero me dio una idea para poder hacer el zoom. Muchas gracias